# Calling Javascript in an iOS web app from Objective-C

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I am developing a web app that is being displayed in a `UIWebView`. The app is loaded locally, i.e, not from a web server. I am communicating from Javascript to ObjC via the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method in the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol.

The last thing I need is to be able to call Javascript functions from ObjC without any page reloads. I hope this is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can call

`-[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]`

whenever you like, not just in response to a delegate method.

Comment: OMG I knew this already. Ha, it's really late here and I had got myself into a panic over having to start the project all over and completely forgot. Thanks. I can go to bed and rest easy now.

Answer (score 4):

You can call any javascript function in your webview by simply using the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method on your webview after you've loaded the webview:

```
[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myJavaScriptFunction(123.0)"];
```

You don't need to reload the webview to send this message (just don't release the webview before you're done).

Answer (score 1):

Could't you just do this by doing a "loadRequest", and passing it an NSURL with contents like like:

```
javascript:myFunction("MyParameter");
```

It should call your function, but not reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

One can use JavaScriptCore framework to run JavaScript code from Objective-C.

```
#import <JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h>

...

JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
[context evaluateScript: @"function greet(name){ return 'Hello, ' + name; }"];
JSValue *function = context[@"greet"];
JSValue* result = [function callWithArguments:@[@"World"]];
[result toString]; // -> Hello, World
```

Here is a demo:

https://github.com/evgenyneu/ios-javascriptcore-demo